# Does recreating a table in SQL erase its contents?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just a real quick question. When modifying a table's columns, and saving requires table recreation, does recreating it erase all of its contents?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are the queries you're running?

Comment: @gaman4455 read my answer .. i think you are modifying columns through SSMS

Comment: You can also stop this happening, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@gman4455 and @Erik .. yes it will erase the data but when you are adding it from SSMS it will take are of eveything .. you dont need to worry about the data .. SSMS will hold data temprory and when it recreates the table it will recreate the data for you.... so you dont need to worry about anything when you modifying a table's columns, and saving through SSMS

Comment: Yeah, I eventually figured that out. I am using SSMS so it seems all good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

recreate = drop table + create (a new) table.

drop means all the data is lost.

If you want to keep the data use the `Alter Table`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can stop this happening in SSMS, follow these steps

> To change the Prevent saving changes that require the table
> re-creation option, follow these steps:
> 1.Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
>
> 2.On the Tools menu, click Options.
>
> 3.In the navigation pane of the Options window, click Designers.
>
> 4.Select or clear the Prevent saving changes that require the table re-creation check box, and then click OK.

taken from [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956176).

Alternatively, you should be able to [ALTER Table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)